# Prestashop 1.7.5 Classic shipping costs are not displayed

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've installed new PS1.7.5 with Classic 1.0.0 theme. 
Cart is showing free shipping all the time despite it is set differently. Shipping is included in order confirmation. An ideas?

test url:

http://212306.w6.wedos.ws/eshop2/en/?id_currency=2

I've already tried reinstall whole PS but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's broken logic of PrestaShop core, as long as there is no carrier selection, PrestaShop will not display it costs in PS 1.7

I've reported it months ago but without success, though if you're sure that there would be no free shipping, you can edit template files, to hide this information if shipping cost is equal to 0

Comment: there is selected carrier (only one) but there is a issue that is it counted in price just not displayed in cart :/ ..the issue is not in please all the time just sometimes....